# Table on its own page

Tags: tables

A last minute decision is going to require some heavy lifting. I was originally just going to show a snapshot of my regression output in my paper (in a small table) but I feel as though my professor would prefer to see each and every coefficient. So, I would like to create a large table that gets its own page and spans both columns. It's the only way i'll be able to fit all of the information anyway. Here's the table I have so far that needs to be moved to its own page and made much larger:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}

%% Remaining Code: Be sure not to reload any already-loaded packages

\usepackage{%booktabs, 
            makecell, %tabularx
            }
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
%\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
%\captionsetup[table]{font=small,
%                     labelfont=bf,
%                     singlelinecheck=no}

%for borders on figures
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\author{}

\begin{document}

%TABLE:
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Estimates of pay-performance sensitivity.}
\label{tab:table1}
OLS regressions of CEO salary and CEO total compensation on change in shareholder wealth. Standard errors in parentheses.

    \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}L ll@{}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Dependent\\ variable}
            &  \thead[l]{CEO\\
                         salary\\
                         (eq. \ref{eqn:first})}
                                    & \thead[l]{CEO total\\
                                            compensation\\
                                            (eq. \ref{eqn:second})} \\
    \midrule
Intercept       &  434.319        & 6250.899                    \\
Change in shareholder wealth (\%~Change)
                & $-0.304$ (.083)   & $-2.638$ (1.551)          \\
    \addlinespace
Adj R-squared   & 0.255         & 0.062                         \\
F-statistic     & $142.13^*$    & $34.10^*$                     \\
Sample Size     & 11537         & 11529                         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
$^{*}$ Significant at the 1\% level.
    \end{table}

\end{document]
```

I understand if you would prefer that I showed you my best effort first, but rather than messing up my paper I thought I would see if anybody would give it a try first.

This is for an idea of the amount of information I need to present:

[image]

UPDATE @MICO (let me know if you'd like an MWE as well)
I think i'll use one table for parameter estimates and the other for comparing goodness of fit measures. Could you help me with this encroaching issue? FYI I simply copy and pasted the table right after the other one and then removed the * symbol from table

[image]

EDIT FOR MICO:

I was using textwidth, switching to column width looks better, but doesnt look like itll fit the third equation:

[image]

Comment: For the second `table` (the unstarred one), are you maybe using `\textwidth` instead of `\columnwidth` as the width of the `tabularx` environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- Change `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` to `\begin{table*}` and `\end{table*}`. This will ensure that table occupies both columns and that it'll show up at the top of the next page.
- Assuming you'll continue to use a `tabularx` environment, and assuming you'll want it to take up the full width of the text block (i.e., both columns), change the first argument of `\begin{tabularx}` from `\columnwidth` to `\textwidth`.

Comment: Mico please see my edit above

Comment: Mico please see my next edit. thanks for all the help btw!

Comment: @texmex - Sorry, i don’t see an equation.

Comment: Mico, I was just speculating. I will try now to add it

Comment: MIco, nevermind, I think I found something that will work.